# What voltage rating does the resistor in this circuit need to be?

Tags: power-electronics, components

In this circuit:

[image: Badly drawn circuit]

the load is protected from transient voltage spikes by the MOV, which clamps at 1kV. 
If the circuit experiences a 6kV spike on the mains supply, will the resistor get hit with 6kV, or since the MOV is clamping at 1KV, will the resistor only see 1kV?

Comment: This circuit makes little sense. Why would you have 180 kOhms in series with your main AC? You won't be able to drive any load with 180,000 Ohms in series. I assume there is some mistake in the circuit. Please clarify it so that we can answer your question intelligently.

Comment: While the circuit is only a drawing so I could ask this question, there is actually a 180kohm resistor on the mains input. It's just for voltage sense.

Comment: MOVs act as a non-linear resistor, so with a 180K source resistance the MOV will likely drag down any voltage readings even at 90% of its clamp rating. For this application suggest you use transzorbs, which have a much tighter avalanche point.

Comment: Thanks Sparky, I'll certainly look into it.
However, the actual MOV I'm using clamps at 710v, which should be well outside the maximum of 275VAC that I would expect to see from a mains input.

Comment: 275 V / 180,000 Ohms = 1.5mA. So with the circuit as is, the current you would deliver to a short-circuit load is 1.5mA. If the load is not a short circuit, then the current will just be less than 1.5mA. This is why you can't have a 180,000 Ohm sense resistor. If there is something I am not getting it is because the question is not clear. So please edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: The question was what voltage would the resistor see if there was a 6kV surge on the mains, with the MOV clamping at 1kV.

Comment: If the MOV truly clamps at 1kV, then 6kV - 1kV = 5kV across the resistor. However as this is a transient event, you probably don't need a resistor rated for the full 5kV. But this is all unsound for many, many reasons. In particular, where did the 6kV come from? If you look into that you will see it probably came from a calculation based on inductance of a wire run and assumed induced current. If you put 180k in series with the same induced current you will have a voltage that is much higher than 5kV.

Comment: I'm going off notes I've read on transient spikes to design for. 6kv seems to be the common highest transient spike that is taken into consideration. The resistor is only spec'd for a 2kV spike.

On the MOV, I may have misunderstood the operation. I thought if it clamped at 1kV, than all voltage greater than 1kV would be across it. Meaning for a 6kV spike there would be 5kV across the MOV and 1kV across the resistor?

Comment: Another option is to move the resistor to the right so it is between the MOV and the load. Then the MOV will protect the combined load of the resistor + the real load. What is the load? Are you sure that the load will function correctly with a 180k resistor in series?

Comment: As a cost saving operation it was suggested that we could put the MOV after the resistor, to lower the energy it would need to dissipate in the event of a surge.

Originally the MOV was on the left on the input, but we have 5 of these inputs and 5 large MOVs is taking up too much board space and they are relatively expensive.

Comment: I hate to beat a dead horse. But your circuit is so different from anything normal that all the usual assumptions about the MOV etc are all wrong anyway. When it is in series with 180k, it will clamp to a much lower voltage. The clamp voltage on an MOV is based on a particular input current (possibly a 1500 Amp current injection). If you succeed in injecting 1500 Amps into a 180k resistor, you will have 270 Megavolts across the resistor. So I think you will not have to worry about a 1500 Amp waveform as long as the resistor is in series with the MOV. 6kV / 180,000 Ohms = 33 mA.

Comment: So once again, what is the load? What is the purpose of this circuit at all? Why do you have 180k in series with the load? Why do you need an MOV at all? Is the circuit going to be tested using an injected current waveform? If so, what is the injected current?

Answer (score 1):

If the circuit gets hit by a 6kV spike, and the MOV clamps at 1kV, then the resistor would have around 5kV across it.  Ultimately, the two components are in series, so the voltages across them must add up to the (momentary) supply voltage.

Comment: On the MOV, I may have misunderstood the operation. I thought if it clamped at 1kV, than all voltage greater than 1kV would be across it. Meaning for a 6kV spike there would be 5kV across the MOV and 1kV across the resistor?

Comment: To the OP: Yes, you misunderstood the MOV operation. The MOV has no way of even knowing what the voltage is across the resistor. The mode of operation you are assuming would require the MOV to sense the voltage across the resistor and adjust its own conductivity accordingly to maintain a peak voltage across the resistor. But the whole scenario of your question is so totally implausible that I really think you you need to tell us a lot more about what you are doing and why you are asking these questions.

Comment: If there were 5kV across the MOV, then there would also be 5kV across the load (they are in parallel).  Which would mean that the MOV has failed to protect the load from the voltage spike.

Comment: Simon that actually makes perfect sense, I had the MOV operation in my head all wrong. Thanks for the explanation it's exactly what I needed.